# Impact, Charcoal на ipad не работают

Tags: css

Подскажите, почему эти шрифты Impact, Charcoal не работают на ipad?
Можно ли как-то проверить, поддерживает ipad эти шрифты?

Comment: Потому что Impact присутствует только в Windows и отсутствует на ipad.

Comment: @andreymal, а если этот шрифт загружен с помощью `@import`, он ведь уже присутствует в ipad, почему он не поддерживается?

Comment: Тогда покажите конкретный пример, что, как и откуда вы загружаете

Comment: @andreymal, что вы имеете ввиду, когда пишете "отсутствует". Шрифт ведь можно загрузить с помощью `@import: url(путь к шрифту')` и так можно загрузить любой шрифт на сайт. А именно на этом сайте шрифт выбирается из slider revolution, там есть опция для текста

Comment: или так можно загрузить шрифт `<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=имя шрифта&subset=cyrillic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>` и потом ведь можно использовать этот шрифт в любом браузере с помощью font-face